# Generate profiling information as part of a .net assembly

Tags: debugging, profiling, profiler, dottrace, ants

Is there a tool that can help me profile .net applications by generating a file and then opening the file with a viewer.
I want to be able to deploy my application and it will constantly generate profiling information, then when my issue reoccurs I can examine that profiling information file.

Comment: What do you mean by "part of a .net assembly"? Assembly is a result of compiling not running.

Is running your application under a profiler not suitable?

Comment: I want the profiler embedded in my process, similar to what postsharp does.
I have a rare issue in my app that causes it to run slowly and I want to distribute it to a test site and have the application generate debug information.

Answer (score 1):

jetbrains dotTrace has self profiling api